# Не работает Javascript с Java в WebView

Tags: android, webview

При нажатии на [Msg to JavaScript](http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html), текст в WebView изменяется, а при нажатии на Say Hello должен выводиться Toast сообщение в activity, а это не происходит на моём планшете Samsung Note 8.0, на телефоне работает замечательно. С чем связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, это связано с версией Android

из [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html):

"Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher."

по ссылке, которая указана в вопросе, аннотация к методу не указана